# Calculate the Euclidean distance of 3 points

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have a data.frame (Centroid) that contains points in virtual 3D space (columns = AV, V and A), each representing a character (column = Character). Each row contains a different character.

```
AV<-c(37.9,10.87,40.05)
V<-c(1.07,1.14,1.9)
A<-c(0.04,-1.23,-1.1)
Character<-c("a","A","b")

centroid = data.frame(AV,V,A,Character)
centroid
     AV    V     A Character
1 37.90 1.07  0.04         a
2 10.87 1.14 -1.23         A
3 40.05 1.90 -1.10         b
```

I wish to know the similarity/dissimilarity between each character. For example, "a" corresponds to 37.9, 1.07 and 0.04 whilst "A" corresponds to 10.87, 1.14, -1.23. I want to know the distance between these characters/ 3 points.

I believe I can calculate this using Euclidean distance between each character, but am unsure of the code to run.

I have attempted to use

```
dist(as.matrix(Centroids))
```

But have been unsuccessful, as this just gives a big print in the console. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to start with learning how to create vectors and matrices, and learning about the different data types in R.  There is a data structure called a `data.frame`, but no `dataframe`.  If you want a vector of numbers, use something like `c(37.9,10.87,40.05)`; `"37.9,10.87,40.05"` is a character vector of length one.  These small syntax details matter a lot.

Comment: @RichieCotton Thank you, I will edit my question to better reflect the structure of my data.frame. I am a new user to R and SO, apologies for the poor structure of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following may be helpful:

```
AV<-c(37.9,10.87,40.05)
V<-c(1.07,1.14,1.9)
A<-c(0.04,-1.23,-1.1)
centroid = data.frame(A,V,AV)
centroid
      A    V    AV
1  0.04 1.07 37.90
2 -1.23 1.14 10.87
3 -1.10 1.90 40.05

mm = as.matrix(centroid)
mm
         A    V    AV
[1,]  0.04 1.07 37.90
[2,] -1.23 1.14 10.87
[3,] -1.10 1.90 40.05

dist(mm)
          1         2
2 27.059909          
3  2.571186 29.190185

as.dist(mm)
       A     V
V  -1.23      
AV -1.10  1.90
```

It is not clear what you mean by "Character<-c(a,A,b)"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The "Character" column contains a mixture of upper and lower-case characters, that correspond to a collection of 3 points in each row.
For example, a is 37.9, 1,07 and 0.04.
I wish to know the difference between each character. I will clarify this in my original question.

Comment: Try creating `centroid` as `centroid = data.frame(AV,V,A,row.names = Character)` (or possibly `centroid <- cbind(AV,V,A); rownames(centroid) <- Character`).